Gstreamer Unable to obtain mp4 video frames
#include <iostream>
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/app/gstappsink.h>

static GstFlowReturn cb_new_sample(GstAppSink *appsink, gpointer user_data) {
    // Get the sample
    GstSample *sample = gst_app_sink_pull_sample(appsink);
    if (!sample) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to pull sample" << std::endl;
        return GST_FLOW_ERROR;
    }

    // Get the buffer
    GstBuffer *buffer = gst_sample_get_buffer(sample);
    if (!buffer) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to get buffer" << std::endl;
        gst_sample_unref(sample);
        return GST_FLOW_ERROR;
    }

    // Get the buffer's data and convert it to the desired format
    GstMapInfo map_info;
    if (!gst_buffer_map(buffer, &map_info, GST_MAP_READ)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to map buffer" << std::endl;
        gst_sample_unref(sample);
        return GST_FLOW_ERROR;
    }

    // Perform frame processing
    // ...

    // Release resources
    gst_buffer_unmap(buffer, &map_info);
    gst_sample_unref(sample);

    return GST_FLOW_OK;
}

static void cb_decodebin_pad_added(GstElement *decodebin, GstPad *pad, gpointer user_data) {
    // Retrieve the sink element from the user data
    GstElement *videoconvert = static_cast<GstElement*>(user_data);

    // Create ghost pad and link it to videoconvert
    GstPad *sink_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(videoconvert, "sink");
    GstPad *ghost_pad = gst_ghost_pad_new(NULL, sink_pad);
    gst_pad_set_active(ghost_pad, TRUE);
    gst_pad_link(pad, ghost_pad);
    gst_object_unref(sink_pad);
    gst_object_unref(ghost_pad);
}

static gboolean cb_message(GstBus *bus, GstMessage *message, gpointer user_data) {
    switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE(message)) {
        case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR: {
            GError *error;
            gchar *debug_info;
            gst_message_parse_error(message, &error, &debug_info);
            g_printerr("Error: %s\n", error->message);
            g_printerr("Debug info: %s\n", debug_info ? debug_info : "none");
            g_clear_error(&error);
            g_free(debug_info);
            break;
        }
        case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
            g_print("End of stream\n");
            break;
        case GST_MESSAGE_WARNING: {
            gchar *debug_info;
            gst_message_parse_warning(message, NULL, &debug_info);
            g_printerr("Warning: %s\n", debug_info ? debug_info : "none");
            g_free(debug_info);
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

int main() {
    // Initialize GStreamer
    gst_init(NULL, NULL);

    // Create the pipeline
    GstElement *pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("video-pipeline");

    // Create the elements
    GstElement *filesrc = gst_element_factory_make("filesrc", "file-source");
    GstElement *decodebin = gst_element_factory_make("decodebin", "decoder");
    GstElement *videoconvert = gst_element_factory_make("videoconvert", "video-converter");
    GstElement *queue = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "video-queue");
    GstElement *appsink = gst_element_factory_make("appsink", "sink");

    if (!pipeline || !filesrc || !decodebin || !videoconvert || !queue || !appsink) {
        std::cerr << "One or more elements could not be created. Exiting." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Set the properties
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(filesrc), "location", "1.mp4", NULL);
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(appsink), "emit-signals", TRUE, "sync", FALSE, NULL);

    // Add the elements to the pipeline
    gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline), filesrc, decodebin, videoconvert, queue, appsink, NULL);

    // Link the elements
    if (!gst_element_link(filesrc, decodebin)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to link filesrc and decodebin" << std::endl;
        gst_object_unref(pipeline);
        return -1;
    }

    // Connect decodebin pad-added signal
    g_signal_connect(decodebin, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK(cb_decodebin_pad_added), videoconvert);

    // Link videoconvert, queue, and appsink
    if (!gst_element_link_many(videoconvert, queue, appsink, NULL)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to link videoconvert, queue, and appsink" << std::endl;
        gst_object_unref(pipeline);
        return -1;
    }

    // Set the appsink callback function
    g_signal_connect(appsink, "new-sample", G_CALLBACK(cb_new_sample), NULL);

    // Set the pipeline state to playing
    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

    // Register a message callback function to handle pipeline messages
    GstBus *bus = gst_element_get_bus(pipeline);
    gst_bus_add_watch(bus, cb_message, NULL);
    gst_object_unref(bus);

    // Wait for the pipeline to finish
    GstMessage *error_message = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered(gst_element_get_bus(pipeline), GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE, GST_MESSAGE_ERROR);
    GstMessage *eos_message = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered(gst_element_get_bus(pipeline), GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE, GST_MESSAGE_EOS);

    // Handle pipeline errors
    if (error_message) {
        GError *error;
        gchar *debug_info;
        gst_message_parse_error(error_message, &error, &debug_info);
        g_printerr("Error: %s\n", error->message);
        g_printerr("Debug info: %s\n", debug_info ? debug_info : "none");
        g_clear_error(&error);
        g_free(debug_info);
        gst_message_unref(error_message);
    }

    // Handle end of stream
    if (eos_message) {
        g_print("End of stream\n");
        gst_message_unref(eos_message);
    }

    // Release resources
    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_object_unref(pipeline);

    return 0;
}



The code can now be compiled and run, but the video file is not displayed. My video files and codes are in the same directory, and all my gstreamer plug-ins are installed.
After my code runs, it keeps running without any response, as if it is blocked. I want him to read the video stream and then use appsink to analyze it frame by frame.
What should I do now so that he can correctly obtain the video stream and play it and let the sink parse each frame?
It is also possible to obtain rtsp for analysis

The pipeline can go into playing state but it seems to not be doing anything after could be related to the filters for the events you added after that.
You already are creating adding the bus watch to handle these. The cb_message callback is already checking for those events so no need to filter for them after. You are also missing the g_main_loop for it to run properly. I suggest taking a look at how the bus_watch is done in the application example in the gstreamer documentation

Just link the decodebin pad to the videoconvert pad normally.
static void cb_decodebin_pad_added(GstElement *decodebin, GstPad *pad, 
gpointer user_data) {
    // Retrieve the sink element from the user data
    GstElement *videoconvert = static_cast<GstElement*>(user_data);

    GstPad *sink_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(videoconvert, "sink");
    gst_pad_link(pad, sink_pad);
    gst_object_unref(sink_pad);
}

